# datepicker not working on dynamic created html

Tags: jquery

i create dynamic div with the input.
with the help of jquery. but problem is that first date picker is working and another is not

```js
$("#addholiday").on( "click", function() {
       var data = $('.holidayinput:last').attr('name').replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
       var i = parseInt(data);
       var name = ++i;
        addRow(".add_holiday_div:last", ".add_holiday_div:last");
        $('.holidayinput:last').attr('name',name)
        $('#removeholiday').fadeIn();
    });

 $('.dpYears').datepicker({
        autoclose: true
    });
    [enter image description here][1]
```

```html
 <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group add_holiday_div">
                        <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Select Holiday Date</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-7">
                            <div data-date-viewmode="years" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-date="<?php echo  date("m-d-Y"); ?>"  class="input-append date dpYears">
                                <input type="text" readonly="" value="<?php echo  date("m-d-Y"); ?>" size="16" class="form-control holidayinput" name="holiday1" id="holiday1">
                                <span class="input-group-btn add-on">
                                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel">
                        <a href="#;" class="fa fa-plus pull-left" id="addholiday"> Add Holiday</a>
                        <a href="#;" class="fa fa-minus pull-right" id="removeholiday"> Remove Holiday</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Why you using datepicker on a div?

Comment: Where is the addRow function? Can you post that code?

Answer (score 0):

Recall the `datepicker` function inside `click` function.

Try to use like this below:

```
$("#addholiday").on( "click", function() {
   var data = $('.holidayinput:last').attr('name').replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' );
   var i = parseInt(data);
   var name = ++i;
    addRow(".add_holiday_div:last", ".add_holiday_div:last");
    $('.holidayinput:last').attr('name',name)
    $('#removeholiday').fadeIn();

    $('.dpYears').datepicker({
         autoclose: true
     });
});

 $('.dpYears').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
});
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Welcome, Please approve my answer.